# GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: docker, terraform

Trying to install terraform on my docker container using wget. I am getting the below error message, please advise.

GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. Unable to establish SSL connection